# Find all record from database using Idiorm

Tags: php, fetch, idiorm

I have lots of records in my database table.If I want to get the all records with Idiorm then I am not successful to find this.
Actually i have 20000 records and I want all with query.It is not possible with Idiorm .

How could it be possible.

Here is My Code :

```
$app = Slim::getInstance();

$recipe= ORM::for_table('recipes')->find_many();
```

Comment: your example should work, is $recipie empty or ?

Comment: above code is working for small records like 200 something , but not for greater then 500

Comment: do you simply get nothing back or jsut a limited set?

Comment: I am getting all record from database.I have more than 20000 records , nothing return.If I set limit 200 it give me exact result

Comment: try `ORM::configure('return_result_sets', true);` if you havent already

Comment: @Dagon Found the solution Thanks so much

Comment: post the solution as an answer, for any one else finding the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for this issue.You need to add these line before you query

```
ORM::configure('return_result_sets', true);
```

Thanks @Dagon for you help to find the correct solutions.